# Counting the number of ones that appear below integer $n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Assume you have a random integer $n$. My question is:

> Is there an algorithm which can, for any input of $n$, count all the ones that appear in all numbers $k\le n$?

For example: $n=0$ gives $0$, $n=1,2,...,8,9 $ gives $1$, $n=10$ gives $2$, $n=11$ gives $4$ etc.

For context this question came up on an entrance exam for a post graduate degree for computational physics, where we were only allowed to use variables, if statements and loops. In the allotted time, which sums up to about half an hour, I came up with this code in C which I explain below (we weren't forced to use C, since again the coding knowledge isn't the point, the problem solving process is):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n,i;
    int sum=0;
    printf("n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    i=1;
    while (i*10<=n) {
        i*=10;
    }
    while (i!=0) {
        if (i==1) {
            if (n>=1) {
                sum+=1;
            }
        } else {
            if (n/i>1) {
                sum+=i+n/i;
            }
            if (n/i==1) {
                sum+=n/i+n%i+1;
            }
        }
        n-=i*(n/i);
        i/=10;
    }
    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The algorithm essentially finds the order of $n$ and stores the related number ($1$ one digit, $10$ for $2$ digits, $100$ for $3$ digits,...) in the variable $i$. Then checks if it's a one digit number and if it is adds $1$ if the number is greater than $0$. If it has $2$ or more digits, the algorithm checks to see whether the first digit is a one (since that's when the most ones will come up for a given number of digits). If it is not a one it adds $i$ and the the integer part of $n/i$, otherwise it adds the the integer part of $n/i$, the modulus of $n$ and $i$ and $1$. After it removes the first digit of $n$, divides $i$ by $10$, and repeats the process till $i$ reaches $0$.

The algorithm can handle up to $2$ digit numbers but falls short afterwards, for example $100$ should have $22$ ones, but I get $2$, $200$ should have $140$ (I think?) ones, but I get $102$ and generally I get wrong answers.

*P.S.* : I wasn't sure whether to ask this question on MathStackExchange or on StackOverflow, since it technically has something to do with coding. I decided to post it here since the coding part of it isn't really the point, the problem solving part of it is. Sorry if the question doesn't belong on the page.

*P.P.S.* : If the question does belong here and someone could help give the right tags, since I wasn't sure what to put, it would be a big help.

Comment: I think one way could be to use the inclusion-exclusion principle

Comment: Or, you could find $\sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot N_k$ where $N_k$ is the number of integers less than $n$ which have exactly $k$ ones. But this ways seems hard if $n$ is not a power of $10$.